# PHP stream_context_create with proxy

Tags: php, http, proxy

I'm currently developing an web application which uses an XML Interface located on a different server, that I have to access via a proxy.

So I tried to set the proxy in a `stream_context_create` array, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$set = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => sprintf(
            'Proxy-Authorization: Basic %s',
            base64_encode(Constants::XML_AUTH)
        ),
        'protocol_version' => '1.1',
        'proxy' => '89.122.180.178:46565'
    )
);
$stream = stream_context_create($set);
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.
If I comment out the `proxy` key i get a `403 Forbidden` Response as it should be.
If I comment in the `proxy` key I receive a `400 Bad Request` Response.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me out? I never did a communication through a proxy before with PHP.

Comment: Is there a body for the 400 response? A 400 error could have many causes, hopefully there will be a meaningful error message in the body of the response. If you add an `'ignore_errors' => TRUE` key to the context array, PHP will return the body of the response regardless of the response status.

Comment: It says `Invalid Request` stating that something in the request is either missing or broken.

Comment: It think I'm going to need to see the full code here including URL (you can blank out the actual host names if you want) and it would definitely help if you can show the HTTP request that is being generated. Do you have cURL available on your server? It give much more granular control over the requests and is a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the proxy declaration is missing the protocol. An [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) has to be specified (according to the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/de/context.http.php)), that contains the protocol (scheme).

So this could work: `'proxy' => 'tcp://89.122.180.178:46565'`. It might be necessary to remove `'protocol_version'` since this may not be required for tcp.

Does that work for you? (or have you already solved it? ... ;-)